# check any data in the webform changed or not asp.net

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a webform with a lot of controls in it mainly Textbox and dropdowns. When the user clicks on the Update button I am supposed to update the values in Database. But I don't want to run the Update code on every update button click. I just want to do it if the user have made any change in the data inside any of my control. Is there any way to understand theuser have  have changed the data or not in the server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a hidden field with value=0 and set a class name for all controls then using [.Change function in JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/change/) and every time a change value occur in any control, set the value of hidden control to 1.
Then in codebehind check the hidden field value on every submit and if the value is 1, run your update code.

```
$(".ClassNameForAllInputs").change(function() {
  $("#<% = HiddenFieldID.ClientID %>").val(1);
});
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort. But I am looking for something much more stable. something entirely from serverside.

Comment: I think if you want to check this in server-side there is no way except read all the current values from database and compare them with input values one by one and if there is a change, set the update flag. The performance is not good obviously.
I don't understand your mean about stability issues.